# SQLite difference between dates in millisecond

Tags: sqlite, date

How can I compute in SQLite the minimum interval of time in milliseconds ?
Ok to give some context,
Here is how my table look like:
[link_budget table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlVVu.png)

So there is this time column, I would like to make a request that gives me the intervals between two consecutive rows in milliseconds.
I don't know how to make my requests.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since SQLite does not have a native datetime data type, instead forcing you to either store as a string or as a number, and you have picked a string, you need to convert it into something that can be calculated upon.

You can use the `julianday` function for this.

To calculate the difference between two values you would simply do this:

```
SELECT julianday('2006-07-01 12:08:15.310')-julianday('2006-07-01 12:08:14.141')
```

This, however, will give you the difference in *days*. One day contains 86400 seconds and thus 86400000 milliseconds, which gives you this:

```
SELECT (julianday('2006-07-01 12:08:15.310')-julianday('2006-07-01 12:08:14.141'))*86400000
```

Note that the precision of the floating point types used internally by SQLite does not have enough precision to get the above value accurate but it should likely be close enough to give you millisecond-precision.

For instance, this:

```
select (julianday('2006-07-01 12:08:14.141')-julianday('2006-07-01 12:08:14.140'))*(86400000)
```

Which should give 1 millisecond of difference gives this result:

```
1.00582838058472
```

Comment: For dates within our lifetimes, a Julian date stored as a `double` has a resolution of 2^-31 day ≈ 40.2 µs.  So, the format itself has millisecond precision, although the intermediate calculations involved might not.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT (STRFTIME('%s', '2021-10-20 18:22:43') - STRFTIME('%s', '2021-10-20 18:22:42'))*1000;
```

for timestamps that contain milliseconds try this:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%s', '2021-10-20 18:22:43.325')*1000 + SUBSTR(STRFTIME('%f', '2021-10-20 18:22:43.325'), 4) -
   ( STRFTIME('%s', '2021-10-20 18:22:42.921')*1000 + SUBSTR(STRFTIME('%f', '2021-10-20 18:22:42.921'), 4) );
```

Comment: This does not work for timestamps that contain milliseconds.

Comment: try updated code

Comment: This is why the difference of 2 julianday() is a better solution.

Comment: absolutly *NO*. because 1.00582838058472 is greater than 1.

Comment: absolutely yes. This is solved by a simple ROUND().

Comment: round(1.2) = 1, round(1.6) = 2. iam very sorry you are wrong. you were supposed to say simple CAST(value AS INTEGER)

Comment: You are wrong. The value that is returned by the difference of 2 julianday() will be rounded to the correct integer because the floating point error will be less than 0.01.